# Как запретить ввод с клавиатуры в richtextbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

В программе нужно запретить пользователю вводить что-либо с клавиатуры в richtextbox, но свойство Enabled = false не подходит, т.к. необходимо оставить возможность пользователю выделять текст мышкой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого выставите флаг у контрола `ReadOnly = true`. Можно будет прокручивать, выделять и копировать текст, а вырезать и вставлять [нет](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-create-a-read-only-text-box-windows-forms)